# How useMemo works with destructuring syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization, react-usememo

On the project that we are developing, I have the task of optimizing the application, including using optimization.
Wrote this piece of code...

```
const {
  searchSupported,
  searchPaginationQuery,
  searchModalTableColumns,
  textFieldAccessor,
  searchSourceContext,
} = useMemo(() => searchHelp, [searchHelp]);
```

Tell me, how **THIS CODE** makes sense?
And if anyone understood, tell me how well **destructuring works with `useMemo ()`**.
Thanks in advance!

Expected Result:
Variables `searchSupported`, `searchPaginationQuery`, `searchModalTableColumns`, `textFieldAccessor`, `searchSourceContext` are memoized.

Comment: `useMemo` just returns `searchHelp` in this case, hence you destructure that object.

Comment: This is totally pointless. Drop the `useMemo` and just write `const {…} = searchHelp;`.

Comment: Where does `searchHelp` come from? Where is it built? *That* is a computation that you might be able to memoize.

Comment: generally `useMemo` is useful when you are doing some computation work with some inputs (props or state variables) and output of the computation is always same for same set of input (pure). Here it makes no sense to simply just return a variable back from the `useMemo` callback function